# Flask обновить токен телеграм боту, если тот изменился

Tags: python, flask, telegram

В данный момент токен боту устанавливается один раз при запуске приложения (в blueprint'e):

```
""" Bot logic """
from flask import request
from shopbot_crm import shopbot_crm_bp
import telebot
from telebot import types
from telebot import apihelper
import secrets


from models import db, TgBot

secret = secrets.token_urlsafe(32)
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен взятый из бд', threaded=False)
bot.remove_webhook()
time.sleep(1)
bot.set_webhook(url="https://mywebhook.com/bot_panel/bot/{}".format(secret))
apihelper.ENABLE_MIDDLEWARE = True

# Дальше идут хенделры бота, которые используют глобальную переменную bot.
```

Предполагается, что токен может быть изменен в БД пользователем через веб-панель.

Вопрос: Как добиться того, чтобы при изменении токена часть кода выше "выполнялась заново"?